# Mathematica stackexchange news letter, some letters gets mangled in email

Tags: feature-request

I get the Mathematica stackexchange weekly newsletter, (Thanks to whoever maintains and send these letters) which I then build to Latex and convert to HTML using tex4ht for archiving and reference.

Since I use Latex, I had to manually edit the email I get each time to handle all the `&lt` and `&gt` letters and change the text around them to verbatim, so it compiles in Latex, it also makes the text harder to read.

It seems any part of the post, which contains `<` or `>` gets mangled up to `&lt` and `&gt` when the email is send to users who subscribed to the weekly letter.  There are also other letters than gets mangled, like `&` which gets changed to `&amp;` and I think there are other letters as well.

Is there a way to change this? so that the text in email remain the same as the post? Here is an example:

The post [function-to-create-a-path-made-of-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-between-a-number](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134424/function-to-create-a-path-made-of-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-between-a-number) was in the letter this week.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But in the email I get, the text shows as

```
I would like to create a function where I can define which 
case I want to use to create a path.

p1 = {40, 48}; p2 = {50, 116}; p3 = {63, 160};
listPurple = Symbol["p" &lt;&gt; ToString[#]] &amp; /@  ...
```

Notice how all the `<` and `>` changed, as well as the `&`. But rest of code seems OK as in the post.

Is there a way to get the emails with the post text as is, without it being mangled up like this, this will make it easier for me to compile these each week. fyi, the archive I maintain is [here](http://12000.org/my_notes/mathematica_stackexchange_letters/index.htm)